# In AEM 6.2 how to make image alt text field mandatory based on image field

Tags: aem

I have two fields in dialog, image field and image alt text field. My requirement is to make the "image alt text" field mandatory if image is authored. But if image is not authored, then "image alt text" should not be mandatory. 
how can we achieve in AEM 6.2 touch ui?

```
                        <image

                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"

                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload"

                            autoStart="{Boolean}false"

                            class="cq-droptarget"

                            fieldDescription=“Authored Image"

                            fieldLabel="Image"

                            fileNameParameter="./fileName"

                            fileReferenceParameter="./fileReference"

                            mimeTypes="[image]"

                            multiple="{Boolean}false"

                            name="./imagedragdrop"

                            title="Upload Image Asset"

                            uploadUrl="${suffix.path}"

                            useHTML5="{Boolean}true"/>

                        <imageAltText

                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"

                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"

                            fieldDescription=“Image alt text"

                            fieldLabel="Image Alt Text"

                            name="./imageAltText"/>
```

Comment: Which granite ui widget are you using for your image? can you post your dialog xml in your question ?

Comment: just added the dialog xml

Comment: I guess, you might want to handle this using listeners.

Comment: Do you have any CFP or SP packages installed? Want to make sure that I match your setup.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to achieve this:

When the file upload widget is authored, it will have the class `is-filled` and when it's not authored, it will not have that class.

**First:**

We need to give both fields a special selector, I'm going with ID's:

Add the property `id="file-upload-special"` to your file upload dialog widget
Add the property `id="alt-special"` to your alt text (textfield) widget

**Second:**

Create a clientlib with the following `categories="[cq.authoring.dialog]"`

**Third:**

Add the following js to the clientlib:

```
// register a validator
$(window).adaptTo("foundation-registry").register("foundation.validation.validator", {
  selector: "#alt-special", // validates the specific alt field
  validate: function(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var $form = $el.closest('form'); // get the form
    var $upload = $form.find('#file-upload-special'); // find the file-upload widget
    if($upload.hasClass('is-filled') && !$el.val()){ // if class exists, return validation msg
        return 'this field is required';
    } else {
        return;
    }
  }
});
```

now the alt field should only be validated if the file-upload is authored.